# How to prevent infinite recursion loop

Tags: java, recursion, infinite-recursion

I can't seem to come up with a solution to my recursion problem. So I have this Version object that holds a list of references to other version objects it is dependent on.

Version

```
{
  "id": "id1",
  "version": "1",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "id": "id2"
    },
    {
      "id": "id3"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I retrieve this object I also have to retrieve it's dependencies as well the dependency's dependencies until there is an eventual end, which would look something like this

VersionDto

```
{
  "id": "id1",
  "version": "1",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "version": "2",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "id": "id4",
          "version": "4",
          "dependencies": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "id3",
      "version": "3",
      "dependencies": []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my Recursive function to retrieve a version

```
public VersionDto getVersion(String id)
{
    //Retrieves from database
    Version version = versionDAO.getVersion(id);

    //Convert to Dto (basic fields)
    VersionDto versionDto = new VersionDto(version);

    //Recursivly retrieve dependencies 
    for (Map<String, String> dep : version.getDependencies()) {
        VersionDto dto = new VersionDto();

        //Recursive call
        dto = getVersion(dep.get("id"));
        versionDto.getDependencies().add(dto);
    }

    return versionDto;
}
```

However I run into the problem of a possible infinite loop in the case where a version could be a dependency to one of the nested dependencies such that v1 -> v2 -> v4 -> v1 causing a infinite repeat.

Any idea how I could solve and prevent this infinite loop, so that if the version all ready occurred earlier it should just skip it?

**Edit: Solution using global list**

```
public VersionDto getVersion(String id)
{

    //Check global list contains version
    if (visited.contains(id)) {
        return null;
    }

    visited.add(docId);

    //Retrieves from database
    Version version = versionDAO.getVersion(id);

    //Convert to Dto (basic fields)
    VersionDto versionDto = new VersionDto(version);

    //Recursivly retrieve dependencies 
    for (Map<String, String> dep : version.getDependencies()) {
        VersionDto dto = new VersionDto();

        //Recursive call
        dto = getVersion(dep.get("id"));
        if(dep!= null) {
        versionDto.getDependencies().add(dto);
        }
    }

    return versionDto;
}
```

Comment: In a nutshell: you either have to mark already visited nodes, or to keep a record of the nodes you have already visited.  In either case you have to check, on encountering a node, whether you have already visited it.

Comment: What behavior, *specifically*, do you want?  Your data has a loop, and your code is dutifully following that loop.

Comment: You should have a structure of all the visited VersionDto and only add them if they are not on the list. Maybe if you add more information about the data structures I can provide further information.

Comment: In all recursive functions, you should have an end condition to avoid stackoverflow. Maybe you could keep a temporary structure that defines which dependencies has already been explored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to be sure that the recursive functions will end, is to put one, or more conditions. You **must** have one, to make sure that it won't go in an infinite loop.

I would suggest to make an array or a list, where you store all the already visited nodes, so when running the recursive function you can be aware that you have already visited a node, and can move to another one.

Comment: I first passed a list through each node that would keep track what has been visited within that path which worked but still had some unnecessary looping. Then I tried a global list which worked much better thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps.

if the dependency of v1 is going to be same always then it works.

````
        dto = getVersion(dep.get("id"));
        //check if the versionDto contains the dependecy already then break the loop here
        versionDto.getDependencies().add(dto);```
````

Answer (score 1):

The infinite recursive loop problem can be very efficiently solved using Jackson libraries. The Jackson libraries comes in handy, particularly, if you are using Hibernate/JPA for persistence. Namely, the @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference annotations would apply to your case.

You have not shown your JPA Entity code, so I can't tell you where exactly you should put these annotations. But, a good example of how to use them is available at

http://springquay.blogspot.com/2016/01/new-approach-to-solve-json-recursive.html

Hope you find it useful!

Comment: Interesting, will have to look more into this. Thanks